# WordPress - Can't run scheduling and cron

Tags: wordpress, cron, scheduled-tasks

I got stuck on scheduling in WP and cron jobs. I need to set a 10min event that calls a function in my class. Basically so far I have a function in the class that does this:

```
private function configureExporter() {
        $this->cronActivation();

        add_action('cron_exporter', array(&$this, 'cronExporter'));
    }

private function cronActivation() {
        if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'cron_exporter' ) ) {
            wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'cron_exporter');
        }
    }

public function cronExporter() {
        // demo, file export, update_option(...)
}
```

Probably missing something but my function doesn't run and I'm not sure about the timings. What did I do wrong?